# std::cout<< ' ' <<std::endl; Outputs a number; why?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I was wondering why I get `A2105376B` when I run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){

  std::cout <<'A' << '   ' <<'B'<<std::endl;
  return 0;

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that c++ doesn't *guarantee* that you will get that output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `'   '` is a multicharacter character literal that has the type int and an implementation defined value.

It seems you mean one-byte character literal `' '` or a string literal `"   "`

From the C++ Standard (2.13.3 Character literals)

> 2 A character literal that does not begin with u8, u, U, or L is an
>   ordinary character literal. An ordinary character literal that
>   contains a single c-char representable in the execution character set
>   has type char, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding
>   of the c-char in the execution character set. An ordinary character
>   literal that contains more than one c-char is a multicharacter
>   literal. **A multicharacter literal, or an ordinary character literal
>   containing a single c-char not representable in the xecution character
>   set, is conditionally-supported, has type int, and has an
>   implementation-defined value.**

Here is a demonstrative program that outputs an integer object if it is initialized by ASCII values of three spaces.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int x=  0x202020;

    std::cout << x << '\n';
    std::cout << '   ' << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2105376
2105376
```

Comment: can you expand more on what the value could be like? and how does it get converted to int? or how is it interpreted? just for my own understanding

Comment: Well, @Waqar just try, as a mental experiment, an attempt to wrap your brain how we humans take individual digits 4, 6, and 8, and get one number 468 out of it. Same thing here, except that the digits are individual bytes, that each can have 256 different values instead of ten different values, since each character is just a byte. Except for 256 values instead of 10, the underlying math is identical.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: but it is just **one** possible implementation. returning always 42 would also be valid...

Comment: @Waqar See my updated post.

Comment: Thanks very much @VladfromMoscow  !